# conditional statement is not working in ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, node-modules

Hello I wants to apply conditional statement in ejs but it is not working in my code "i wants that when i select the  a specific value(not using transportation) then buton shows otherwise not show but its showing only - (else condition) on every selection from dropdown" in developer tools it is showing the conditional statement code like this https://ibb.co/60ZWcXh that it is not taking

conditional statement

```
  <%if (locals.students == "noTransportation") { %>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="" id="">
         Migrate to Applicants
       </button>
     <%} else { %>
       -
     <% } %>
```

complete students_list.ejs

```
  <select class="form-control changeDropDown" id="transportation">
             <option value="applications">Applications</option>
             <option value="transportation">Using Transportation</option>
             <option value="noTransportation">Not Using Transportation</option>
             <option value="All">All</option>

         </select>

     <%if (locals.students == "noTransportation") { %>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="" id="">
         Migrate to Applicants
       </button>
     <%} else { %>
       -
     <% } %>
```

controller:

```
  in controller the code in comments ////data migration code//// is for this conditional statement but its not working 

      paste.ofcode.org/RGu9t7Fm3uNPNKiczNP2p9
```

how can I resolve this issue

Comment: Did you try to console.log `locals.students` in your JS code before you send it?

Comment: nthing in js code

Comment: @matrixersp it says undefined

Comment: That's why it shows the code in else block, you need to give `locals.students` the value  "noTransportation" if you want to show the code in if block

Comment: done but i wants that when i select the not using transportation then buton shows otherwise not show but its showing button on every selection

Comment: @matrixersp now I write itbut its not working and not showing any error paste.ofcode.org/zZ8uhjb4FkPjfec9Tkcezy

Answer (score 0):

If you put a `console.log(locals.students)` right above the `if` condition, you'll see (in your `node`'s terminal) that `locals.students` has a value that's different than `noTransportation`. Add it like this:

```
 <select class="form-control changeDropDown" id="transportation">
             <option value="applications">Applications</option>
             <option value="transportation">Using Transportation</option>
             <option value="noTransportation">Not Using Transportation</option>
             <option value="All">All</option>

         </select>

     <% console.log("====================", locals.students) %>
     <%if (locals.students == "noTransportation") { %>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="" id="">
         Migrate to Applicants
       </button>
     <%} else { %>
       -
     <% } %>
```

If you want to see that the `if` actually works properly, you can put, **temporarily**, instead of the `console.log(....)`:

```
<% locals.students = "noTransportation" %>
```

**Update:**

There's no quick & easy solution that could fit in an answer on stackoverflow for what you currently have.

Some ideas for you to follow:

- the code inside `<% .. %>` is executed on the server.
- the selection change of the select box is executed in the browser
- in order to have the button show whenever a change is made, you can:

  - add a client side js function to hide/show the button whenever `$("#transportation")` changes - but this alone will save **nothing** in your DB
  - make a server request and redraw the whole page when `$("#transportation")` changes, so that your `ejs` can be executed.

Comment: i wants that when i select the not using transportation then buton shows otherwise not show but its showing button on every selection by adding this: <% locals.students = "noTransportation" %>

Comment: in your controller, where you have 
             `res.render("/students_list", {
                  students: students
              });` - that `students` var is not set anywhere.

Comment: m new to node can u plz tell me what should I do

Comment: now I write itbut its not working and not showing any error paste.ofcode.org/zZ8uhjb4FkPjfec9Tkcezy